# How to specify type parameter

Tags: ruby, sorbet

How to specify type parameter using sorbet?

For example, I want to annotate a method with an argument of type `A` returning generic type `T[A]`.

```rb
def build_array(value) 
  [value]
end
```

The output type depends on the input type:

```rb
build_array(42) #=> return Array[Integer]
build_array('42') #=> return Array[String]
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can accomplish this using `type_parameters`:

```
# typed: true
extend T::Sig

sig do
  type_parameters(:T)
  .params(value: T.type_parameter(:T))
  .returns(T::Array[T.type_parameter(:T)])
end
def build_array(value) 
  [value]
end

x = build_array(5)
T.reveal_type(build_array(42))   # T::Array[Integer]
T.reveal_type(build_array('42')) # T::Array[String]
```

Here's a [sorbet.run link with the above code](https://sorbet.run/#%23%20typed%3A%20true%0Aextend%20T%3A%3ASig%0A%0Asig%20do%0A%20%20type_parameters(%3AT)%0A%20%20.params(value%3A%20T.type_parameter(%3AT))%0A%20%20.returns(T%3A%3AArray%5BT.type_parameter(%3AT)%5D)%0Aend%0Adef%20build_array(value)%20%0A%20%20%5Bvalue%5D%0Aend%0A%0Ax%20%3D%20build_array(5)%0AT.reveal_type(build_array(42))%20%20%20%23%20T%3A%3AArray%5BInteger%5D%0AT.reveal_type(build_array('42'))%20%23%20T%3A%3AArray%5BString%5D).

Answer (score 2):

You can try using Generic for the method definition.

Eg:

```
  sig do
    type_parameters(:U)
    .params(
      blk: T.proc.params(arg0: Elem).returns(T.type_parameter(:U)),
    )
    .returns(Box[T.type_parameter(:U)])
  end
  def map(&blk)
    Box.new(blk.call(@x))
  end
```

See example from [sorbet.run](https://sorbet.run/#%23%20typed%3A%20true%0Aclass%20Box%0A%20%20extend%20T%3A%3ASig%0A%20%20extend%20T%3A%3AGeneric%0A%20%20Elem%20%3D%20type_member%0A%0A%20%20sig%20%7Bparams(x%3A%20Elem).void%7D%0A%20%20def%20initialize(x)%0A%20%20%20%20%40x%3Dx%0A%20%20end%0A%0A%20%20sig%20do%0A%20%20%20%20type_parameters(%3AU)%0A%20%20%20%20.params(%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20blk%3A%20T.proc.params(arg0%3A%20Elem).returns(T.type_parameter(%3AU))%2C%0A%20%20%20%20)%0A%20%20%20%20.returns(Box%5BT.type_parameter(%3AU)%5D)%0A%20%20end%0A%20%20def%20map(%26blk)%0A%20%20%20%20Box.new(blk.call(%40x))%0A%20%20end%0Aend%0A%0ABox%5BInteger%5D.new(0).map(%26%3Asucc).map(%26%3Afoo))

Comment: Thanks! Updated. @aysamanra provided a better answer with working example. Kudo to him.